# Преобразование чисел в слова с++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, строки

В общем, мне нужно написать алгоритм который преобразовывает число в слова на русском, в процессе наткнулся на, то что я выхожу за пределы массива и программа вылетает когда ввожу числа от 10к до 100к,не могли бы,подсказать возможное решение.Это мой первый вопрос на форуме, так, что если я, что то не так написал извиняюсь.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <string> 
using namespace std;
std::string nameForNumber(long long number);

/*пример самый наглядный будет:
* Рассмотрим случай, когда number равно 21.Здесь number / 10 это 2, так что tens[number / 10] это "двадцать".
* Далее number % 10 это 1, так что convert(number % 10) это "один".
* Тогда конечная строка будет "двадцать один"
* И так со всем числами
*/
std::vector<std::string> thousands = { " тысяча", " тысячи", " тысяч" };


std::vector<std::string> one = { "", " одна", " две", " три", " четыре", " пять", " шесть", " семь", " восемь", " девять" };
std::vector<std::string> ones = { "", " один", " два", " три", " четыре", " пять", " шесть", " семь", " восемь", " девять" };
std::vector<std::string> teens = { " десять", " одиннадцать", " двенадцать", " тринадцать", " четырнадцать", " пятнадцать", " шестнадцать", " семнадцать", " восемнадцать", " девятнадцать" };
std::vector<std::string> tens = { "", "", " двадцать", " тридцать", " сорок", " пятьдесят", " шестьдесят", " семьдесят", " восемьдесят", " девяносто" };
std::vector<std::string> hundredth = { ""," сто", " двести", " триста", " четыреста", " пятьсот", " шестьсот", " семьсот", " восемьсот", " девятьсот",};

std::string thousandEnding(int number) {
    int lastDigit = number % 10;
    int penultimateDigit = (number / 10) % 10;

    if (penultimateDigit == 1) {  // Для чисел 10-19 всегда "тысяч"
        return thousands[2];
    }
    else if (lastDigit == 1) {  // Для чисел, оканчивающихся на 1 (кроме 11), "тысяча"
        return thousands[0];
    }
    else if (lastDigit >= 2 && lastDigit <= 4) {  // Для чисел, оканчивающихся на 2-4 (кроме 12-14), "тысячи"
        return thousands[1];
    }
    else {  // Во всех остальных случаях "тысяч"
        return thousands[2];
    }
}
std::string nameForNumber(long long number) {
    //единицы
    if (number < 10) {
        return ones[number];
    }
    //числительные
    else if (number < 20) {
        return teens[number - 10];
    }
    //десятки
    else if (number < 100) {
        return tens[number / 10] + nameForNumber(number % 10);
    }
    //сотни
    else if (number < 1000) {
        return hundredth[number / 100] +  nameForNumber(number % 100);
    }
    //тысячи
    else if (number < 1000000) {
        return one[number / 1000] + thousandEnding(number / 1000) + nameForNumber(number % 1000);//Тут ошибка от 10к до 100к
    }
    //миллионы
    else if (number < 1000000000) {
        return nameForNumber(number / 1000000) + " миллионов" + nameForNumber(number % 1000000);//еще не доделалано
    }
    //миллиарды 
    else if (number < 1000000000000) {
        return nameForNumber(number / 1000000000) + " миллиардов" + nameForNumber(number % 1000000000);//еще не доделалано
    }
    return "error";
}


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    long long input;
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
        cin >> input;
        cout << "\n" << nameForNumber(input) << endl;
        cout << "\n\n" << endl;
    } while (input > 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно в этот момент использовать ту же схему, которую вы используете для чисел `>= 10**6`:

```
else if (number < 1000000) {
    return nameForNumber(number / 1000) + thousandEnding(number / 1000) + nameForNumber(number % 1000);//Тут ошибка от 10к до 100к
}
```

---

UPD: вот так можно, но мне уже начинает думаться, что этот подход *корявый*

```
std::string nameForNumber(long long number, bool flag=false) {
    //единицы
    if (number < 10) {
        return flag ? one[number] : ones[number];
    }
    //числительные
    else if (number < 20) {
        return teens[number - 10];
    }
    //десятки
    else if (number < 100) {
        return tens[number / 10] + nameForNumber(number % 10);
    }
    //сотни
    else if (number < 1000) {
        return hundredth[number / 100] +  nameForNumber(number % 100);
    }
    //тысячи
    else if (number < 1000000) {
        return nameForNumber(number / 1000, true) + thousandEnding(number / 1000) + nameForNumber(number % 1000);//Тут ошибка от 10к до 100к
    }
    //миллионы
    else if (number < 1000000000) {
        return nameForNumber(number / 1000000) + " миллионов" + nameForNumber(number % 1000000);//еще не доделалано
    }
    //миллиарды 
    else if (number < 1000000000000) {
        return nameForNumber(number / 1000000000) + " миллиардов" + nameForNumber(number % 1000000000);//еще не доделалано
    }
    return "error";
}
```

и нужно не забыть изменить объявление функции на такое

```
std::string nameForNumber(long long number, bool flag);
```

Comment: действительно,видимо я не много запутался,но теперь для чисел 1 и 2 слово берется из массива ones и получается "один тысяча" и "два тысячи" как можно это исправить

Comment: @winlogon обновил ответ. но что-то мне кажется, что это *коряво* уже выглядит